# Linux - How to setup cups.conf to access cups web interface from remote machines

Tags: cups

I have a Linux server that is intended to be a print server.
I need to enable remote administration of the printers using the cups web interface.
I have read about this around but I'm missing something.
In the cupsd.conf I added the ip addresses range We want to access the cups administration in the `<Location />, <Location /admin>` and `<Location /admin/conf>` sections, restarted the service but I can not access the web interface from remote machines.
below a part of my cupsd.conf

```
#   Sample configuration file for the Common UNIX Printing System (CUPS)
#   scheduler.  See "man cupsd.conf" for a complete description of this
#   file.
#

# Log general information in error_log - change "info" to "debug" for
# troubleshooting...
LogLevel info

# Administrator user group...
SystemGroup root


# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen localhost:631

Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all

# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType Basic

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow 127.0.0.1
  Allow 10.2.*
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Encryption Required
  Order allow,deny
  Allow 10.2.4.*
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  Allow 10.2.4.*
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job CUPS-Move-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @lp
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM @lp
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM @lp
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @lp
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

DefaultPolicy default

# easy is a very relaxed policy
<Policy easy>
  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit All>
    Satisfy any
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>
</Policy>

#
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself.

Commenting out the line:

```
Listen localhost:631
```

And adding the line:

```
Port 631
```

Does the magic!